# Array attribute of an object

Tags: javascript

In a non-array attribute of an object:

```
function myObj()
{
  this.code = "code";
  this.name = "name";
}
```

I can retrieve their values using:

```
  myCode = myObj.code;
```

or:

```
  myCode = myObj["code"];
```

With arrays:

```
function myObj()
{
  this.code = ["code1","code2"];
  this.name = ["name1","name2"];
}
```

I have to to get "code2" so my syntax should be:

```
  myCode = myObj.code[1];
```

Now my problem is, how can I get "code2" using the other way (the one the uses braces and the attribute enclosed in braces)?

Comment: Javascript objects have properties, HTML and XML elements have attributes. The term you are looking for is "square bracket notation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
myCode = myObj['code'][1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..^^, I have tried it before but didn't work. But when I tried it now it did work. Must have missed something before. Anyways, thank you very much. ^^,